# Retrieve Arguments of a Workflow (with default values)?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Given is a Workflow Foundation 4 runtime that is working against a website ;)

We need to get the arguments of workflows to show the user an editor to enter the arguments. For that we need all arguments with names, types and - default values, as well as an indication whether an argument is required.

Workflows are stored as XAML files.

How to do that? The data seems to be in the Activity Metadata which seems to be not avaialble outside the Workflow. In addition, the Workflow Engine ModelService is for the Designer and has a lot of overhead.

Any easy way to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 2):

I've already done something similar. Reflection might be your best (and only) option if you want a generic approach.

```
// Just an holder for InArgument informations
class InArgumentInfo
{
    public string InArgumentName { get; set; }
    public string InArgumentDescription { get; set; }
    public bool InArgumentIsRequired { get; set; }
}

static ICollection<InArgumentInfo> GetInArgumentsInfos(Activity activity)
{
    var properties = activity.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(p => typeof(InArgument).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
        .ToList();

    var argumentsCollection = new Collection<InArgumentInfo>();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var descAttribute = property
            .GetCustomAttributes(false)
            .OfType<DescriptionAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();

        string description = descAttribute != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(descAttribute.Description) ?
            descAttribute.Description :
            string.Empty;

        bool isRequired = property
            .GetCustomAttributes(false)
            .OfType<RequiredArgumentAttribute>()
            .Any();

        argumentsCollection.Add(new InArgumentInfo
        {
            InArgumentName = property.Name,
            InArgumentDescription = description,
            InArgumentIsRequired = isRequired
        });
    }

    return argumentsCollection;
}
```

This way you can not only retrieve the argument's name but also other information hold by the argument's attributes. For example I choose to give argument an user-friendly name through *[Description]* attribute (eg. instead of MyPropertyName user sees "My Property Name").

**Note**: if you can ensure that you activity is an [ActivityBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.activitybuilder.aspx) or [DynamicActivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.dynamicactivity.aspx) they both have [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.activitybuilder.properties.aspx) property that you can use, but the principle is the same.

Comment: +1. You could reuse DynamicActivityProperty(that is well known and holds all those infos) and make a method that checks if is ActivityBuilder or DynamicActivity and return Properties prop and in other cases use reflection to get the props. ;]

Comment: Sure, that's an option. My guess is that *Properties* property also uses reflection behind-the-scene. *DynamicActivity* implements [ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Load it as DynamicActivity and iterate over `Properties` property

```
var dynamicActivity = ActivityXamlServices.Load(foo) as DynamicActivity
foreach(DynamicActivityProperty prop in dynamicActivity.Properties)
{
   // ...
}
```

**UPDATE**: Missed default value part

```
foreach (var prop in dynamicActivity .Properties)
{
    object defaultValue;
    if (prop.Value == null)
    {
        defaultValue = null;
    }
    else
    {
        Type genericTypeDefinition = prop.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        if (genericTypeDefinition == typeof(InArgument<>) || genericTypeDefinition == typeof(InOutArgument<>))
        {
            var valueProp = prop.Value.GetType().GetProperty("Expression", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            var expression = valueProp.GetValue(prop.Value, null);

            var expressionValueProp = expression.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
            defaultValue = expressionValueProp.GetValue(expression, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Not totally guaranteed, there are some checks you have to do.

Comment: That cast from *Activity* to *DynamicActivity* isn't valid.

Comment: Are you sure? DynamicActivity : Activity.
This activity was created through an ActivityBuilder on you workflow designer?

Comment: What if it's a *CustomCodeActivity* created through code? That cast isn't *always* valid.

Comment: I thought he was loading an activity with arguments from XAML because he said "workflows"(the entire ones), so I presumed that he was loading a dynamic activity created on ActivityBuilder with arguments created in arguments tab.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but of course it was useful. That's a valid option but only if you ensure that original activity is an *ActivityBuilder* or *DynamicActivity* which isn't *always* true.

Comment: The original activity is a workflow. We currently compile it but will move to XAML with it - so it is a full workflow. it is NOT a custom code activity etc. - we talk of "root" activities here, basically the worfklow. I dont start parts of a workflow in the UI ;)